# mongo db isodate to node date output mismatch

Tags: node.js, mongodb

newb wandering around node / mongo on localhost os x 10.6.8 Not using middleware as I want to understand what's going first.

Imported multiple documents into mongo. Attempting to find by date but getting a mismatch.
The date is correct in mongo and finding from the mongo shell but off by a day earlier in node.

mongo

```
db.dates.find({date: new Date('1957-07-05')})
```

output

```
{ "story" : "poster" : "admin", "date" : ISODate("1957-07-05T00:00:00Z"), "_id" : ObjectId("519d59eb4b35dd72180002bf") }
```

node

```
collection.find({date:new Date('1957-07-05')}).toArray(function(err, items) {
console.log(items);
});
```

console output

```
[ { poster: 'admin',
date: Thu Jul 04 1957 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT),
_id: 519d59eb4b35dd72180002bf } ]
```

SOLUTION(?)

Anyone getting here it seems like 
    .toISOString()
from above
    console.log(items[0].date);
    var wdf = new Date(items[0].date).toISOString();
    console.log(wdf);

Answer (score 1):

Node uses your current timezone (in this case `EDT (GMT-0400)`) when you construct a date without an explicit timezone, while mongo just uses `UTC`.

Comment: Thanks! Pointed me in the right direction.
Anyone getting here seems like .toISOString() is working.
    console.log(items[0].date);
    var wdf = new Date(items[0].date).toISOString();
    console.log(wdf);